# Apps inside different app pools on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, .net

I saw a guy a couple of days ago and he was putting his apps inside different app pools for each app. For example:

- example.com inside *examplePool* - .net 4.0 integrated mode
- example2.com inside *example2Pool* - .net 4.0 integrated mode
- example3.com inside *example3Pool* - .net 4.0 integrated mode

I would understand the logic if the settings was different, but they weren't.

What I am doing is the complete opposite. All of my .net 4 apps (there are nearly 20) are running under one app pool.

So what is the best way of doing this on IIS 7.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [Managing Application Pools in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753449%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) TechNet page, it is simply to separate applications from each other. Here's the relevant bit.

> An *application pool* is a group of one or more URLs that are served by
>   a worker process or a set of worker processes. Application pools set
>   boundaries for the applications they contain, which means that any
>   applications that are running outside a given application pool cannot
>   affect the applications in the application pool.
>
> Application pools offer the following benefits:
>
> - Improved server and application performance. You can assign
>     resource-intensive applications to their own application pools so that
>     the performance of other applications does not decrease.
> - Improved application availability. If an application in one
>     application pool fails, applications in other application pools are
>     not affected.
> - Improved security. By isolating applications, you reduce the chance
>     that one application will access the resources of another application.

Comment: so, it is good to separate them but if you don't, there is no performance effect?

Comment: There *could* be a performance effect, but it depends on what the other applications in the app pool are doing. Personally, I'd have multiple app pools for the case that one app pool crashes it doesn't prevent the other apps in the app pool from running.

Comment: hmm, thanks. I also have some subdomains they are running as seperate apps. do you think they should sit inside their own app pool?

Comment: I'd say that if it's the same app then it goes in the same app pool, even if part of it exists on a subdomain. Other people may have other ideas, that's just my opinion.

Comment: but inside the iis, it is viewed as a seperate app. So, it can go under a different app pool but doesn't have to.

Comment: With App Pools, my rules of thumb are: Baseline of one per site, then as many as you need, but as few as you can get away with.